# Como consumir API - Pix Santander para gerar Token em C#

Tags: c#, api, http-request

Tudo bem?

Estou com dificuldades para obter um token para consumir uma API do santander (pix), para gerar o token eu utilizo o Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, os testes no PostMan estão retornando tudo certo, mas na hora de implementar no C# não recebo o status Unauthorized.
Eu já criei dois métodos diferentes para tentar obter o token mas o resultado foi o mesmo, vou colocar os métodos abaixo

O Santander usa uma pseudo-linguagem para orientar na chamada do método, que é essa:

```
With hhtpRequest
Open "POST", https://pix.santander.com.br/sandbox/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials
Set Header As "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Set Header As "Authorization:", "Basic " + FunBase64 (ClientId + ":" + ClientSecret) Set Body As ("client_id=" & ClientId & "&client_secret=" & ClientSecret)
Set Certificate As "C:\Users\**UserId**\Documents\Certificados\..."
Send
End With
```

O primeiro método que testei foi esse:

```
    public string ObterToken1()
    {
        var url = @"https://pix.santander.com.br/sandbox/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials";

        var client = new RestClient(url);

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + FormatarBase64(client_id + ":" + client_secret));
        request.AddParameter("client_id", client_id);
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", client_secret);

        var result = client.Execute(request);
        if(result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return "Deu Bom";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Houston i have a problem";
        }

    }
```

O segundo que testei foi esse:

```
    public string ObterToken2()
    {
        string endPoint = @"https://pix.santander.com.br/sandbox/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials";

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var data = new[]    //client_id e client_secret são as credenciais fornecidas pelo santader
                {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Authorization", "Basic" + FormatarBase64(client_id + ":" + client_secret )),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", client_id),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", client_secret)
            
           
              };
        var result = client.PostAsync(endPoint, new FormUrlEncodedContent(data)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        if(result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return "Deu Bom";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Houston i have a problem";
        }
    }
```

Onde posso estar errando para não conseguir o retorno desejado ?

Comment: Pelo postman esta correto e no codigo c# esta retornando qual mensagem?

Comment: Pelo postman eu recebo status 200 e recebo o json com o token que preciso , porém na minha implementação de c# eu recebo {"ErrorCode" : "invalid_client", "Error" :"Client identifier is required"}

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução que não dependa da API (por exemplo, simulando os dados já retornados). Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu método utilizando `RestSharp` eu não consegui identificar qual o erro, desconfio do seu método `FormatarBase64` ja que não sei o que ele faz.

Já o seu método utilizando `HttpClient` você esta passando o `Content-Type` e a `Authorization` no corpo da requisição ao invés de ser no cabeçalho.

```
 string clientID = "";
 string clientSecret = "";

 HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
 _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://pix.santander.com.br/sandbox/oauth/token");
 _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", $"{Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{clientID}:{clientSecret}"))}");
 _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        
 var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 dict.Add("client_id", clientID);
 dict.Add("client_secret", clientSecret);
 var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "?grant_type=client_credentials") { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
        
 var res = await _client.SendAsync(req);

 var json = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Apenas para complementar sobre o uso do `HttpClient`.

Da forma como ele está nesse método, você jamais deve usa-lo assim.
Sugiro a leitura desse [artigo](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcos, funcionou perfeitamente :-)

Comment: Imagina! Editei a minha resposta apenas colocando um link do artigo sobre o uso do HttpClient. Acredito que seja importante você usa-lo corretamente para não ter problemas, já que voce esta fazendo um serviço para usar o PIX que exige muitas requisições.

Comment: obrigado amigo :-)